# Google Earth Imagery

Tags: post-processing

Would anyone know the best way to analyze terrain photography taken using Google Earth? I'm doing independent archaeological research in Peru and have found some interesting sites but they are very difficult to see because of their age and erosion without using whatever basic filters I have access to. How can I bring out the details of ancient foundations, Geoglyphs, etc., these sites are located in the desert. I'd appreciate any suggestions, thx!

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but:

Google Earth isn't a very good source for aerial imagery for archeology. Aerial pictures for archeology benefit from a variety of factors:

- grazing light: pictures are taken right after dawn or a bit before dusk to enhance shadows
- vegetation: plants don't grow the same if the soil is different. This means the pictures aren't the same depending on seasons.
- There are even pictures [where the morning dew reveals fatures](https://archeologie.culture.gouv.fr/archeologie-aerienne/en/first-aerial-flyovers)

On the other hand GE pictures are usually taken around noon in summer to minimize shadows, so about the opposite of what you would want.